# Is it possible to install Ubuntu on my iPod Touch 2G?

Tags: ipod-touch, unix

I just wander whether it is possible to install Ubuntu in my iPod Touch 2G just for fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, but very impractical for several reasons.

- Ubuntu is built for Intel x86/x64 officially, and unofficially for the PowerPC (old Macs and the PS3). iPod/iPhone/iPad is built off the ARM architecture, meaning you'd need to do a full rebuild of every single package.
- You'd have to exploit the phone to load Ubuntu on to it, and use an exploited bootloader to load anything but a signed iOS.
- You'd have to write custom drivers for everything you expected to work, such as the webcam, virtual keyboard, etc.

I'd look into the progress of Android on iPhone. Last I know, Froyo was running alright on an iPhone 3G. Since the full chain of trust has been compromised on all devices except the Verizon iPhone and the iPad 2, it's possible, but the Android port is suffering all the issues I listed above.

Edit: Ubuntu will also expect much more RAM and a much faster processor than the older iDevices have, but the newer devices are more up to par.

Comment: Does Android run on my iPod Touch 2G also?

Comment: Here's iDroid's compatibility matrix. http://www.idroidproject.org/wiki/Status It looks like they've barely got anything supported on there unfortunately, but a few things are marked as work in progress. I'm stuck in the same boat with an iPhone 3GS.

Comment: Ubuntu has an ARM build - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/arm.  It is still an unsupported platform, however, so it is essentially only for those who do not need to ask about to do these things.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's probably for the new wave of Windows 8 tablets that will come with ARM processors. Even a year later, I'd be super impressed with someone who could get Ubuntu running on an iThing.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe anyone has put together a way to do that. Even jailbreaking uses the iOS. Moreover, what do you expect to *do* on a 320x240 screen with no keyboard?

Comment: hmmm...to say the truth I did not think about keyboard, i don't know.

Comment: It'd be a really cool project, if someone (maybe you!) were to start writing drivers and bootstrap code. People got Linux on older iPods, so why not these far more powerful devices?

Comment: I would be happy to do that but I am just a beginner in Linux.